# What does denormalizing mean?

Tags: mongodb, embedding, denormalization

While reading the article http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3 chapter: "**Rules of Thumb: Your Guide Through the Rainbow**" i came across the words: embedding and denormalizing.

> One: favor embedding unless there is a compelling reason not to
>
> Five: Consider the write/read ratio when denormalizing. A field that will mostly be read and only seldom updated is a good candidate for denormalization: if you denormalize a field that is updated frequently then the extra work of finding and updating all the instances is likely to overwhelm the savings that you get from denormalizing.

I know embedding is nesting documents, instead of writing seperate tables/collections.

But i have no clue what denormalizing means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denormalization is the opposite of [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), a good practice to design relational databases like MySQL, where you split up one logical dataset into separated tables to reduce redundancy.

Because MongoDB does not support joins of tables you prefere to duplicate an attribute into two collections if the attribute is read often and less updated.

E.G.: You want to save data about a person and want to save the gender of the Person:

In a SQL database you would create a table person and a table gender, store a foreign key of the genders ID in the person table and perform a join to get the full information. This way "male" and "female" only exists once as a value.

In MongoDB you would save the gender in every Person so the value "male" and "female" can exist multiple times but the lookup is faster because the data is tightly coupled in one object of a collection.

Comment: Does this mean gender lives only in person or on its own too?

Comment: denormalized a gender online exists in a person and not for its own. If you want to use it on an other place, you have to create it there, too.